# Facebook Unity SDK Webview Rotation

Tags: facebook-unity-sdk

When there is no FB app or FB native integration I wish to change the session open behaviour to [self.session openWithBehavior:FBSessionLoginBehaviorForcingWebView instead of allowing the FB SDK to switch out to safari (switching out from a large game on older devices will generally cause the app to be closed with memory issues). My issue is that with a Landscape only Unity application the FB web view popup appears to only want to be portrait. Unfortunately as all of the web view code is hidden away in the library I can't seem to change this.

Anyone know of a way to force the web view to be portrait?

Comment: Using Unity 4.6b19 + Unity Facebook 6.0 SDK + iOS8

Comment: Did you find any possible solution/workaround for this issue?

Comment: I'm afraid not - had to stick with safari. There was a bug raised with facebook about the app requests staying as portrait always and this is apparently fixed in the next version. I did get round this issue by just using the latest facebook native SDK library file with the unity SDK